# python2.7.12 do not contain numpy also not pip so i cant run my program in gromacs

Tags: python, g++

I manually download Python 2.7.12 because in my charm file the python2.7.15+ does not work.

In my Python 2.7.12 there is no pip command, so I cant install networkx & numpy packages.

What can I do to run

`python cgenff_charmm2gmx.py JZ4 jz4_fix.mol2 jz4.str charmm36-mar2019.ff`

I am trying to boostrap pip on my python 2.7.12. But that also gives an error:

> suchi@DESKTOP-TR0BVV2:/mnt/c/Users/Microsoft/Desktop/Gromacs/Complex1$ python cgenff_charmm2gmx_py3.py UNK1 jz4_fix.mol2
>    jz4.str charmm36-jul2017.ff
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "cgenff_charmm2gmx_py3.py", line 50, in 
>       import numpy as np
>   ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
>   suchi@DESKTOP-TR0BVV2:/mnt/c/Users/Microsoft/Desktop/Gromacs/Complex1$

```
============ DONE ============
Conversion complete.
The molecule topology has been written to jz4.itp
Additional parameters needed by the molecule are written to jz4.prm, which needs to be included in the system .top
============ DONE ============
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install pip manually first. Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and then excute it 
using the command below.

```
# download the get-pip.py
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

# use these 2 commands to make sure you have selected the right python
which python
python --version

# install pip, should work for both python2 and python3
python get-pip.py
```

And then, you can install almost every package you need.
For example,

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

to install `numpy`.

Comment: how can I execute get-pip.py?

Comment: First, use `which python` to check which python you are using and make sure you have selelcted the one you want; then `python get-pip.py`.

Comment: By the way, you can consider anaconda, which is easier to configurate. And conda creates separated environments, so you will not get different versions of python messed up.